# Which statistical test should i use, ANOVA or Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney?

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, count-data, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I am struggling to find out which statistical test I should use to analyse my data. My independent variable is "Treatment" (2 levels- Treated and not treated) and my dependent variable is "The number of parasites found".

I think I need to use an ANOVA test or Mann-Whitney but I'm not very sure.

Comment: How would you use ANOVA and Mann-Whitney? Why do you find those appropriate?

Comment: The correct approach depends on the distribution of the DV. Are the counts of parasites normally distributed? Is the variance the same under both treatments?

Comment: No the counts are not normally distributed and the variance is not the same under both treatments

Comment: It's my understanding that ANOVA tests are used when the question is about causality and whether one (explanatory) variable has an effect on another (response) variable. With the Mann-Whitney, it's used when there are two populations/treatment groups and measures the likelihood that a value taken from treatment will be higher than a value taken from the non treatment group.

Comment: Wilcox here means Wilcoxon. You’re probably being misled by the name of an R function.

Comment: Welcome to the site. What are the *group* sample sizes? I don’t think we should jump to the conclusion that normality is violated just yet. In some contexts, reporting estimates from both tests would be appropriate. It would be interesting if you could share some summary statistics with us or show us the distribution of incidents/counts.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. The group sample sizes are 10 for each treatment group. I've included some summary stats below.

Comment: Not-Treated- 26, 17, 9, 25, 6, 0, 18, 24, 7, 13                                                            Treated- 4, 4, 10, 20, 4, 17, 12, 11, 9, 7                                                          Mean no. of parasites found- Not-treated= 14.5, treated= 9.8                                                                                           Standard deviation- Not-treated= 8.959787, treated = 5.49343

Comment: Thank you. Modify your question a bit to note this and why you think one approach is more appropriate. This may generate a better discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome.

I assume you have independent observations between the groups. Put differently, this is *not* a paired sample. Participants are either in the *treated* condition (i.e., treatment group) or in the *untreated* condition (i.e., control group).

> I am struggling to find out which statistical test I should use to analyze my data.

It is often prudent to explore multiple approaches, even if one is superior. I would begin with a parametric approach, such as a 'one-way' ANOVA, or as I call it, an independent samples *t*-test. Once you explore differences in group *means*, you can test for differences non-parametrically, as with a Mann-Whitney *U*-Test. Today, conducting multiple tests is as easy as a few extra key strokes. It is relatively fast and computationally inexpensive.

Upon examination of your outcomes, the group distributions will be oddly shaped. You are likely to see skewed distributions, in part because you are working with integer (count) observations. Just make sure the individual observations are recognized by your software as ‘numeric’ values (not categorical).

Also, most of your participants produce unique outcomes, so a quick histogram shows a distribution that looks more uniform than anything. Interestingly, your sample *medians* closely mirror your sample *means*. Vertical dotted lines show the medians. In psychology and biomedical fields, it is not uncommon to see ugly distribution like this.

[image]

Upon inspection of the group distributions, we see that the mean and median number of parasitic observations are lower in the treated condition. The box plots below clearly indicate a wider spread of parasites found among individuals comprising the control group.

[image]

> I think I need to use an ANOVA test or Mann-Whitney but I'm not very sure

As indicated earlier, you should try both. Should you begin with a parametric *t*-test, some software packages (definitely R) will default to a degrees of freedom adjustment known as the Welch-Satterthwaite approximation to the degrees of freedom. This is one method of dealing with unequal variances.

In your case, with equal (but small) group sample sizes and unequal variances, it is appropriate to also use the Mann-Whitney *U*-Test, also recognized as the Wilcoxon-Rank Sum Test. Be mindful, the null hypothesis is a statement regarding *equality of the population distributions*. You are assuming the samples were obtained from populations with identical distributions. In other words, you are testing if the sampled populations exhibit stochastic equality. You may have seen it expressed in papers in the following manner:

$$
H_{0}: P(X < Y) = P(X > Y)
$$

$$
H_{1}: P(X < Y) \neq P(X > Y)
$$

Framing this as a test of equality/inequality of the sample *medians* is not appropriate in most contexts. Some texts often refer to this as a shift model. What complicates inferences drawn with respect to location shifts is that our distributions have to be similarly shaped. Since this is often not the case in practice, we only make statements regarding stochastic equality/inequality. Your earlier comment correctly indicates that this method allows you to make statements regarding whether values in one group are different than the values in another group. Put differently, this approach will allow you to test if one group exhibits stochastic dominance.

Try out these different approaches. And, don't feel you have to try just one thing.

Comment: Thank you so much Tom, this is so useful and makes perfect sense!

Comment: Anytime! If I’ve addressed your question give it a check. If not you can follow-up here.

Comment: I get a P-value of 0.22, indicating a weak difference. A virtue of Mann-Whitney is that it allows a estimate of pr(count if untreated > count if treated) which here is 0.665. Indicative but not definitive given the sample sizes.